# How can I insert whole numbers in between elements with decimals in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I am passing an object with 5 arrays to my function. One of the properties is called 'Indexes'. What this function is doing is filling in the array with zeros in ascending order, all other arrays follow the Indexes array as their index so if the Indexes array is [1,3] it will fill it with [1,2,3] and all arrays will have 0 in position 2.

My problem is when Indexes contain .5 (work-related, so I have to roll with it), if I have [43, 44.5, 45] I want to get [43, 44, 44.5, 45]. But the way I wrote my code seems to skip with whole numbers completely, and I think I am making it more complicated for myself than it needs to be.

Here's the function

```
function fillMissingValues(csv) {
    const indexes = csv.Indexes;
    const allReads = csv['All reads'];
    const trimmedByAdapterOrQuality = csv['Trimmed by Adapter or Quality'];
    const trimmedByAdapter = csv['Trimmed by adapter'];
    const trimmedByQuality = csv['Trimmed by quality'];

    const filledIndexes = [];
    const filledAllReads = [];
    const filledTrimmedByAdapterOrQuality = [];
    const filledTrimmedByAdapter = [];
    const filledTrimmedByQuality = [];

    let lastIndex = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++) {
        const index = indexes[i];
        const value = allReads[i];
        const taq = trimmedByAdapterOrQuality[i];
        const ta = trimmedByAdapter[i];
        const tq = trimmedByQuality[i];

        while (lastIndex < index) {
            filledIndexes.push(lastIndex);
            filledAllReads.push(0);
            filledTrimmedByAdapterOrQuality.push(0);
            filledTrimmedByAdapter.push(0);
            filledTrimmedByQuality.push(0);
            lastIndex++;
        }

        filledIndexes.push(index);
        filledAllReads.push(value);
        filledTrimmedByAdapterOrQuality.push(taq);
        filledTrimmedByAdapter.push(ta);
        filledTrimmedByQuality.push(tq);
        lastIndex++;
    }

    // Fill the remaining indexes with zeros
    const maxIndex = Math.max(...indexes);
    while (lastIndex <= maxIndex) {
        filledIndexes.push(lastIndex);
        filledAllReads.push(0);
        filledTrimmedByAdapterOrQuality.push(0);
        filledTrimmedByAdapter.push(0);
        filledTrimmedByQuality.push(0);
        lastIndex++;
    }

    const filledCSV = {
        Indexes: filledIndexes,
        'All reads': filledAllReads,
        'Trimmed by Adapter or Quality': filledTrimmedByAdapterOrQuality,
        'Trimmed by adapter': filledTrimmedByAdapter,
        'Trimmed by quality': filledTrimmedByQuality
    };

    return filledCSV;
}
```

Example of passing data,

```
csv = {
        Indexes:[ 3, 4, 6.5, 8]
        'All reads': [1, 2, 3, 4],
        'Trimmed by Adapter or Quality': [1, 2, 3, 4],
        'Trimmed by adapter': [1, 2, 3, 4],
        'Trimmed by quality': [1, 2, 3, 4],
}
```

so output should be

```
filledCSV = {
        Indexes:[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6.5, 7, 8]
        'All reads': [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 4],
        'Trimmed by Adapter or Quality': [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 4],
        'Trimmed by adapter': [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 4],
        'Trimmed by quality': [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 4],
}
```

Comment: Was this down voted just because of incorrect format and spell checks??

Comment: It's hard to understand what your question is, and what the problem you are having is.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, english is not my first language so I am sorry for that. I just want to insert missing values for decimal. For example, Indexes array can be [3, 5.5, 7], in case of Index of 5.5 with value A, increment by A/2 at position 5 and A/2 for position 6. So I should get [0,1,2,3,4,5,5.5,6,7]

Comment: Is the fraction always `.5` or could it be any non-integer value?

Comment: @Barmar it will always be .5

Answer (score 0):

Create an array with all the integers from 0 to `Math.max(...indexes)`.

Merge `indexes` into this array, remove duplicates, and sort it.

Loop over this combined array. If the element is in `indexes`, push the corresponding elements of all the other properties into the corresponding property in `filledCSV`. If not, push `0`.

```js
const csv = {
  Indexes: [3, 4, 6.5, 8],
  'All reads': [1, 2, 3, 4],
  'Trimmed by Adapter or Quality': [5, 4, 3, 2],
  'Trimmed by adapter': [5, 10, 15, 20],
  'Trimmed by quality': [10, 15, 18, 30],
}

const filledCSV = Object.fromEntries(Object.keys(csv).map(key => [key, []]));

let maxIndex = Math.max(...csv.Indexes);
let origIndexMap = Object.fromEntries(csv.Indexes.map((index, i) => [index, i]));
let filledIndexes = [...new Set([...Array(maxIndex).keys(), ...csv.Indexes])];
filledIndexes.sort((a, b) => a - b);
filledCSV.Indexes = filledIndexes;

filledIndexes.forEach(index => {
  let origIndex = origIndexMap[index];
  Object.entries(filledCSV).forEach(([key, array]) => {
    if (key != 'Indexes') {
      array.push(origIndex === undefined ? 0 : csv[key][origIndex]);
    }
  });
});

console.log(filledCSV);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Loop over `Indexes` with an incremented value `idx` from `0` and fill a new array `filled` while collecting indices (`found`) of the existing values in `filled`.
2. For the remaining arrays, allocate arrays with zeros and write the existing values in the existing indices

```js
const {Indexes} = csv, found = Array(Indexes.length), filled = [];

let idx = -1, i = 0;
while(i < Indexes.length){
  if(++idx < Indexes[i]) {
    filled.push(idx);
  }else{
    idx = Indexes[i]|0;
    found[i] = filled.length;
    filled.push(Indexes[i++]);
  }
}
 
const filledCSV = {Indexes:filled};
for(const k in csv){
  if(k === 'Indexes') continue;
  const arr = filledCSV[k] ??= Array(filled.length).fill(0);
  const from = csv[k];
  found.forEach((i, j) => arr[i] = from[j]);
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(filledCSV));
```

```html
<script>
const csv = {
  Indexes: [3, 4, 6.5, 8],
  'All reads': [1, 2, 3, 4],
  'Trimmed by Adapter or Quality': [5, 4, 3, 2],
  'Trimmed by adapter': [5, 10, 15, 20],
  'Trimmed by quality': [10, 15, 18, 30],
}
</script>
```

```
` Chrome/122
------------------------------------------------
Alexander   1.00x | x1000000 264 269 273 277 278
Barmar     13.83x |  x100000 365 371 378 379 387
------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```js
const csv = {
  Indexes: [3, 4, 6.5, 8],
  'All reads': [1, 2, 3, 4],
  'Trimmed by Adapter or Quality': [5, 4, 3, 2],
  'Trimmed by adapter': [5, 10, 15, 20],
  'Trimmed by quality': [10, 15, 18, 30],
}

// @benchmark Barmar
{
const filledCSV = Object.fromEntries(Object.keys(csv).map(key => [key, []]));

let maxIndex = Math.max(...csv.Indexes);
let origIndexMap = Object.fromEntries(csv.Indexes.map((index, i) => [index, i]));
let filledIndexes = [...new Set([...Array(maxIndex).keys(), ...csv.Indexes])];
filledIndexes.sort((a, b) => a - b);
filledCSV.Indexes = filledIndexes;

filledIndexes.forEach(index => {
  let origIndex = origIndexMap[index];
  Object.entries(filledCSV).forEach(([key, array]) => {
    if (key != 'Indexes') {
      array.push(origIndex === undefined ? 0 : csv[key][origIndex]);
    }
  });
});
filledCSV;
}

// @benchmark Alexander
{
const {Indexes} = csv, found = Array(Indexes.length), filled = [];

let idx = -1, i = 0;
while(i < Indexes.length){
  if(++idx < Indexes[i]) {
    filled.push(idx);
  }else{
    idx = Indexes[i]|0;
    found[i] = filled.length;
    filled.push(Indexes[i++]);
  }
}
 
const filledCSV = {Indexes:filled};
for(const k in csv){
  if(k === 'Indexes') continue;
  const arr = filledCSV[k] ??= Array(filled.length).fill(0);
  const from = csv[k];
  found.forEach((i, j) => arr[i] = from[j]);
}
filledCSV;
}


/*@skip*/ fetch('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js').then(r => r.text().then(eval));
```